# Visual Studio 2012 - Conditional Using (service reference)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, production-environment

In my code I currently have:

```
#if (DEBUG)
using GetNewRecordNumber = {dev web service reference}.GetNewRecordNumber;
#else
using GetNewRecordNumber = {prod web service reference}.GetNewRecordNumber;
#endif
```

So that I can do:

```
 using (GetNewRecordNumber.Tickets_GetNewRecordNumber getNum = new GetNewRecordNumber.Tickets_GetNewRecordNumber())
```

in my code. This all works fine, but I would like to make the switch in the Application Settings so that I can change it at run time. Is there a way to pull this off so the switch can happen on run time other then duplicating code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor directive works jut before the compilation, so it won't work at rune time. Sorry, but you must pull off the "#" directives and use the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings instead.

Comment: Sure, but how do I do that with the using statement for the references as noted above? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you would consider this duplicating code, but perhaps the most straightforward approach would be to make a wrapper class for your services and use that wrapper class in places like the above.  You're already duplicating tons of code with these #if blocks, so using a wrapper might even reduce your total code and make it cleaner.

Another option would be to manually modify your service references so that they inherit from a common interface that defines all the members you need, but that may not be a great idea if you need to update the references often.